# Bluestacks: no games starting

Tags: bluestacks

I have been playing High School Story on latest version of Bluestacks. I had no issues and was at level 7 after which it stopped working. So I re-installed bluestacks, a clean installation, and wiped all of my data. Since then I am not able to play any games on it. It start to load, goes to black screen and then back to home screen. Since then I have many times clean installed Bluestacks, use old builds but with no luck. I am using Windows 7 32-bit. Is there any solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution could be to use another emulator, Some of option for you are:

**AMI DuOS** (http://amiduos.com) : As per my experience this is best android emulator so far as per usage i didn't find any cons in this emulator, only cons could be it is not freeware but 10 bucks are nothing by quality of product.

**Genymotion** (https://www.genymotion.com) : Another good alternative but as per my experience many games are not working.

**Andy** (http://www.andyroid.net) : One more good option for you but it can run less number of game comparing with bluestacks and AMI DuOS

I have played High school story in AMI DuOS and it is working although i have not reached at level 7 but you can give try as it provides 30 day trial for free and I have not tested this game in other emulator because i am not using them now.

Comment: Good alternatives but I have been have other issues with Ami Duos recently.

Comment: you can report issues to their support here http://amiduos.com/support